# Google Sheets match/intersect of two sets

Tags: filter, google-sheets, match

I have keywords in one sheet:

[image]

And results in another sheet:

[image]

I want to find if any of the words in `search` exist in `keywords`. And if there is a word that is in both, the `results` will show any `result` that has the keywords.

```
=join(", ",filter(A3:A5,match(split(B3:B5,", "),split(F3,", "))))
```

In this case, I get an error **#VALUE!** where it should say `Result 1, Result 2`

The error says

> FILTER range must be a single row or a single column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get the result you were looking for by using

`=QUERY(A3:B5,"Select A where B contains '"&SPLIT(D2,",")&"'",0)`

So I had the SEARCH values placed in D2. If you want the results in another sheet, you'd use `Sheetname!A3:B5`

Comment: if you add `=SPLIT(TRIM(D2),", ")` to E2 the formula below would also return if "ranch" is found.

`=QUERY(A3:B5,"Select A where B contains '"&E2&"' or B contains '"&F2&"'",0)`